# Bijection between $ \{0,1\}^\omega$ and $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{Z}_{+})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is problem $3$ in section $7$ of Munkres Topology.

Let $X$ be the two element set $\{0,1\}$. Show that there is a bijective correspondence between the set $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb Z_+)$ and the uncountable cartesian product $X^\omega$.

How do I construct this? I am just looking for a hint, not the full answer. I don't know where to start.

Comment: Munkres has P(Z+).A typo?

Comment: Hint: Would working with $\mathscr P(\omega)$ be easier?

Comment: Yes it should be Z+

Comment: "Yes it should be", use the [edit] function please and fix your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the cartesian product an element $(a_1,a_2,a_3\ldots)$ is completely specified when the set of indices $i\in Z^+$  with $a_i=1$ is given. (the complementary set sppecifying zeros).  This is the mapping  sending an element of the cartesian product to a subset of positive integers. Check that this is the bijection.

Comment: @JB071098: That is pretty much the whole solution. I haven't closed this question as one of the infinitely many duplicates yet because you only asked for a hint. If you want a hint that explains more, this is practically a duplicate already.